# iOS - Closing a Subclassed UIView from view's uibutton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, subclass

I have a custom subclassed uiview I created to display in-app notifications.
I can call the view just fine, but am having problems dismissing it using a uibutton (embedded in the custom view)

When the button is pressed, the app crashes and I get this error:

> **UPDATE - Fixed the above issue, but now only the button dismisses, and not the actual view. See updated code below.**

```
-(id)initWithMessage:(NSString *)message{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -70, 320, 60)];
    if (self) {        
        //Add Image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notice-drop-down"];
        UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [self addSubview:background];

        //Add Label
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, self.frame.size.height/2-25, 300, 50)];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [label setText:message];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Hand of Sean" size:16]];
        //NSLog(@"FONT FAMILIES\n%@",[UIFont familyNames]);


        [self addSubview:label];

        //Add Close Button
        UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, self.frame.size.height/2-15, 30, 30)];
        UIImage *closeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notice-close"];
        [closeButton setImage:closeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeNoticeDropDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:closeButton];

        //Animate In
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                              delay:0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.frame = CGRectMake(0,70,320,60);
                         }
                         completion:nil
         ];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)closeNoticeDropDown:(id)self{
    NoticeDropDown *notice = (NoticeDropDown *)self;
    NSLog(@"Frame: %f",notice.frame.size.width);
    //Animate In
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         notice.frame = CGRectMake(0,-70,320,60);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [notice removeFromSuperview];
                         //notice = nil;
                     }
     ];
}
```

View call from another view controller:

```
noticeDropDown = [[NoticeDropDown alloc] initWithMessage:message];
[self.view insertSubview:noticeDropDown belowSubview:hudContainerTop];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your method to be a class method but are sending the message to an instance. If you want it to be a class method still, pass [NoticeDropDown class] as the target parameter to your addTarget:action:forControlEvemts: method. Otherwise replace the "+" with a "-" in the method declaration.

Also- when UIControl actions have sender parameters it will send the control as the sender - so you will get a UIButton instead of your view.

My recommendation is to change your action to an instance method and replace "sender" with "self".

I apologize for formatting I'm posting from my phone. I'll try to fix when back at a computer.

EDIT:

Change your updated method like so:

```
-(void)closeNoticeDropDown:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Frame: %f",notice.frame.size.width);
    //Animate In
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.frame = CGRectMake(0,-70,320,60);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self removeFromSuperview];
                     }
     ];
}
```

You don't need to pass `self` into a method, it always exists.

Comment: Thanks Carl! So I changed it to an instance method, and now it works (sort of). It does what you said, it removes the BUTTON and not the actual view. What is the proper way to send the view and not the button?

Comment: @james so you kept it as a class method? I think that is making it too hard on yourself actually. I think making it an instance method should give you the easiest time. I'll update my answer.

Comment: argh! So dumb of me. Can't believe I missed that... Awesome! Thanks Carl!

Answer (score 1):

You probably try to call your method on your view instance (something like `[noticeDropDown closeNoticeDropDown:...]`) but `closeNoticeDropDown:` is a class method and you should call it this way:

```
[NoticeDropDown closeNoticeDropDown: noticeDropDown];
```

There's also few things in your animation code that look wrong:

- `[UIView commitAnimations];` calls should be removed as they are used in pair with [UIView beginAnimations:... context:...] method, they're not required with block-based animation
- `[sender removeFromSuperview];` call should go in animation's completion block, otherwise it will be called before your animation is even started and you won't get desired effect

Comment: Hi Vladimir! Thanks for your help. So I am not trying to call the method that way. The embedded button is what calls the method. I have used the below solution to help fix my problem. Now I just have to figure out how to get the method to remove the view and not just the button.

Comment: Oh and I appreciate the input about the other items. I altered those and things still work fine. I had just copied that code a long time ago and it always worked for other apps so I never really questioned it. Thanks for the additional input!